# Button click to setOnGenericMotionListener event using mouse scroll work

Tags: java, android, mouseevent, motionevent

Sir,
    I am work with on button key and it show some value like for Eg:5 if i have move mouse cursor point to button, then on setOnGenericMotionListener event using mouse scroll the Eg: 5 is varied to increase and decrease value depend upon mouse scroll but now i want to move any place of my mouse cursor point have need to set setOnGenericMotionListener event using mouse scroll event to work on that particular button how it possible to perform this event?

> Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
int x,f;
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);                  
    button.setOnGenericMotionListener(new OnGenericMotionListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:             
                if (event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL) > 0.0f)
                {
                    x=Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
                    f=x+5;
                    button.setText(""+f); 
                }
                else
                {
                    x=Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
                    f=x-5;
                    button.setText(""+f); 
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use this method to detect the touch event.
In View.onGenericmotionEvent description:

```
    /**
     * Implement this method to handle generic motion events.
     * <p>
     * Generic motion events describe joystick movements, mouse hovers, track pad
     * touches, scroll wheel movements and other input events.  The
     * {@link MotionEvent#getSource() source} of the motion event specifies
     * the class of input that was received.  Implementations of this method
     * must examine the bits in the source before processing the event.
     * The following code example shows how this is done.
     * </p><p>
     * Generic motion events with source class {@link InputDevice#SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER}
     * are delivered to the view under the pointer.  All other generic motion events are
     * delivered to the focused view.
     * </p>
     * <pre> public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     *     if (event.isFromSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_JOYSTICK)) {
     *         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
     *             // process the joystick movement...
     *             return true;
     *         }
     *     }
     *     if (event.isFromSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
     *         switch (event.getAction()) {
     *             case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
     *                 // process the mouse hover movement...
     *                 return true;
     *             case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
     *                 // process the scroll wheel movement...
     *                 return true;
     *         }
     *     }
     *     return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @param event The generic motion event being processed.
     * @return True if the event was handled, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
```

Some cases of usage for this method you can find [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.view.View.OnGenericMotionListener)

Btw, you should use `GestureDetector` instead to handle your gesture.